# How to to reposition the unordered list element <li> in dropdown menu so it will display in the dropdown column

Tags: javascript, html, css

[The li elements not in the dropdown box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTt51.png)

**Please help me to reposition the unordered list element `<li>` in dropdown menu so it will display in the dropdown column.**

Below my HTML and CSS code:

```css
body, ul, li {
  font-size:14px; 
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height:21px;
  text-align:left;
  margin:0;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;   
}

/* Navigation Bar */

#menu {
  list-style:none;    
  margin: 50px auto auto auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;     
  background: #1a1a1a;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
  background: #1a1a1a; 
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
}
body {behavior: url("csshover3.htc");}  
#menu li .drop {
  background:url("img/drop.gif") 
  no-repeat right 8px; 
}
#menu li {
  border-style: none;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-width: medium;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
  margin-right:30px;
  margin-top:15px;
  top: -3px;
  left: 368px;
} 
#menu li:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;     
  background: #F4F4F4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#menu li a {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px; 
  color: #EEEEEE;
  display:block;
  outline:0;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#menu li:hover a {
  color:#161616;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu li .drop {
  padding-right:21px;
  background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 8px;
}
#menu li:hover .drop {
  background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 7px;
}
h1.header-line, h2.header-line,
h3.header-line, h4.header-line,
h5.header-line, h6.header-line{
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  position:relative;
} 
/* Drop Down */

.dropdown_1column, .dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, .dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
  margin:4px auto;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
  text-align:left;
  padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
  border:1px solid #777777;
  border-top:none;     
  /* Gradient background */
  background:#F4F4F4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB)); 
  /* Rounded Corners */
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.dropdown_1column {width: 140px;}
.dropdown_2columns {width: 280px;}
.dropdown_3columns {width: 420px;}
.dropdown_4columns {width: 560px;}
.dropdown_5columns {width: 700px;}

#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
  left:-1px;
  top:auto;
}

/* Columns */

.col_1,.col_2,.col_3,.col_4,.col_5 {
  display:inline;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.col_1 {width:150px;}
.col_2 {width:270px;}
.col_3 {width:410px;}
.col_4 {width:550px;}
.col_5 {width:690px;}

.col_1 ul li {
  float:right;
  display:inline;
}
/* Right alignment */

#menu .menu_right {
  float:right;
 margin-right:200px;
}
#menu li:hover .align_right {
  left:auto;
  right:-1px;
  top:auto;
}

/* Drop Down Content Stylings */

#menu p, #menu h2, #menu h3, #menu ul li {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height:21px;
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:left;
  /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF; */
}
#menu h2 {
  font-size:21px;
  font-weight:400;
  letter-spacing:-1px;
  margin:7px 0 14px 0;
  padding-bottom:14px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #666666;
}
#menu h3 {
  font-size:14px;
  margin:7px 0 14px 0;
  padding-bottom:7px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #888888;
}
#menu p {
  line-height:18px;
  margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

#menu li:hover div a {
  font-size:12px;
  color:#015b86;
}
#menu li:hover div a:hover {
  color:#029feb;
}
.strong {
  font-weight:bold;
}
.italic {
  font-style:italic;
}
.imgshadow {
  background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:4px;
  border:1px solid #777777;
  margin-top:5px;
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
}
.img_left { /* Image sticks to the left */
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  margin:5px 15px 5px 5px;
}
#menu li .black_box {
  background-color:#333333;
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;

  /* Rounded Corners */
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  /* Shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
}
#menu li ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 12px 0;
}
#menu li ul li {
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:24px;
  position:relative;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  float:none;
  text-align:left;
  width:130px;
}
#menu li ul li:hover {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#menu li .greybox li {
  background:#F4F4F4;
  border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
  margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
  padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
  width:116px;

  /* Rounded Corners */
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu li .greybox li:hover {
  background:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
  margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul id="menu" style="height: 55px; z-index: 100; left: 1px;">
        <li style="text-align: left; top: -3px; left: 6px; width: 160px; ">
        <a class="drop" style="font-size: x-large"> &#9776; Menu</a>
            <div class="dropdown_5columns">
                <!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
                <div class="col_5">
                    <h3 style="text-align:center">INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col_1">
                    <h3>Home</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">IT Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">IT Online Application</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Silt Intranet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Silt.com</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col_1">
                    <h3>Training Guide</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Meeting Room</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">IT Orentiation Guide</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">KingSoft</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Security Awareness</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col_1">
                    <h3>Organization</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Organization Chart</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">*****</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col_1">
                    <h3>Policies & Procedure</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mailbox Quota</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Escalation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DRP</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="auto-style1">Welcome to IT Portal</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know how to re-position the `<li>` element so it will display in the drop down column. Now my `<li>` elements display out of the drop down column to the center of the page.

Comment: how it will look ? will u explain

Comment: Welcome! put brief code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add `left:0` in `#menu li ul li` class and it's work

```css
body, ul, li {
  font-size:14px; 
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height:21px;
  text-align:left;
  margin:0;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;       
}

/* Navigation Bar */

#menu {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 50px auto auto auto;        
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: -50px; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */  

/* Background color and gradients */
  background: #1a1a1a;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
  background: #1a1a1a;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
}
body {behavior: url("csshover3.htc");}

#menu li .drop {
  background:url("img/drop.gif") 
  no-repeat right 8px; 
}
#menu li {
  border-style: none;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-width: medium;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
  margin-right:30px;
  margin-top:15px;
  top: -3px;
  left: 368px;
}

#menu li:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;

/* Background color and gradients */

  background: #F4F4F4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));

/* Rounded corners */

  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#menu li a {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px; 
  color: #EEEEEE;
  display:block;
  outline:0;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#menu li:hover a {
  color:#161616;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu li .drop {
  padding-right:21px;
  background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 8px;
}
#menu li:hover .drop {
  background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 7px;
}
h1.header-line,
h2.header-line,
h3.header-line,
h4.header-line,
h5.header-line,
h6.header-line{
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  position:relative;
}

/* Drop Down */

.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
.dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
  margin:4px auto;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
  text-align:left;
  padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
  border:1px solid #777777;
  border-top:none;

  /* Gradient background */
  background:#F4F4F4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));

  /* Rounded Corners */
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.dropdown_1column {width: 140px;}
.dropdown_2columns {width: 280px;}
.dropdown_3columns {width: 420px;}
.dropdown_4columns {width: 560px;}
.dropdown_5columns {width: 700px;}

#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
  left:-1px;
  top:auto;
}

/* Columns */
.col_1,
.col_2,
.col_3,
.col_4,
.col_5 {
  display:inline;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.col_1 {width:150px;}
.col_2 {width:270px;}
.col_3 {width:410px;}
.col_4 {width:550px;}
.col_5 {width:690px;}

.col_1 ul li {
  float:right;
  display:inline;
}
/* Right alignment */

#menu .menu_right {
  float:right;
  margin-right:200px;
}

#menu li:hover .align_right {
  left:auto;
  right:-1px;
  top:auto;
}

/* Drop Down Content Stylings */

#menu p, #menu h2, #menu h3, #menu ul li {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height:21px;
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:left;
  /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF; */
}
#menu h2 {
  font-size:21px;
  font-weight:400;
  letter-spacing:-1px;
  margin:7px 0 14px 0;
  padding-bottom:14px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #666666;
}
#menu h3 {
  font-size:14px;
  margin:7px 0 14px 0;
  padding-bottom:7px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #888888;
}
#menu p {
  line-height:18px;
  margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

#menu li:hover div a {
  font-size:12px;
  color:#015b86;
}
#menu li:hover div a:hover {
  color:#029feb;
}
.strong {
  font-weight:bold;
}
.italic {
  font-style:italic;
}
.imgshadow {
  background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:4px;
  border:1px solid #777777;
  margin-top:5px;
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
}
.img_left { /* Image sticks to the left */
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  margin:5px 15px 5px 5px;
}
#menu li .black_box {
  background-color:#333333;
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;

  /* Rounded Corners */
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  /* Shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
}
#menu li ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 12px 0;
}
#menu li ul li {
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:24px;
  position:relative;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  float:none;
  text-align:left;
  width:130px;
  left:0;
}
#menu li ul li:hover {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#menu li .greybox li {
  background:#F4F4F4;
  border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
  margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
  padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
  width:116px;
}

/* Rounded Corners */
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu li .greybox li:hover {
background:#ffffff;
border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <ul id="menu" style="height: 55px; z-index: 100; left: 1px;">
       <li style="text-align: left; top: -3px; left: 6px; width: 160px; ">
          <a class="drop" style="font-size: x-large">&#9776; Menu </a>              
         <div class="dropdown_5columns">
             <!-- Begin 4 columns container -->

             <div class="col_5">
                 <h3 style="text-align:center">INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY</h3>
             </div>
             <div class="col_1">
                 <h3>Home</h3>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">IT Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">IT Online Application</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Silt Intranet</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Silt.com</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="col_1">
                 <h3>Training Guide</h3>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Meeting Room</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">IT Orentiation Guide</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">KingSoft</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Security Awareness</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="col_1">
                 <h3>Organization</h3>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Organization Chart</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">*****</a></li>

                 </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="col_1">
                 <h3>Policies & Procedure</h3>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Mailbox Quota</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Escalation</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">DRP</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="auto-style1">Welcome to IT Portal</li>
   </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help You :)